# Create a treeview from a recursiv list C# Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, treeview

i would like populate a treeview from a recursiv list,
I have an item which also contains a list of items and so on.
The number and levels of childnodes of parentnodes is not limitted.

here is the class:

```
public class item
        {
            public int Id;
            public string texte;
            public List<item> listeItems;
            public string status;
            public item()
            {
                this.listeItems = new List<item>();
            }
        }
```

for example:

```
item1 --> item11
      |-> item12
      |-> item13

item2 --> item21
      |-> item22
      |-> item23 --> item 211
                 |-> item 212 --> item 2111
                              |->........
```

how i can do it ?
thank you in advance !!

Comment: I think you'll need `Parent` property

Comment: There is no other methods not require Parent property ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public HtmlGenericControl RenderMenu(List<item> nodes)
{
    if (nodes == null)
        return null;

    var ul = new HtmlGenericControl("ul");

    foreach (Node node in nodes)
    {
        var li = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
        li.InnerText = node.texte;

        if(node.listeItems != null)
        {
            li.Controls.Add(RenderMenu(node.listeItems));
        }

        ul.Controls.Add(li);
    }

    return ul;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something like:

```
void Populate(item i)
{
    if (i == null)
      return;
     foreach (var child in i)
     {
        Populate(child);
     }
     i.Id = something;
     i.texte = something;
     i.status = something;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the number of child nodes are not limited, the better way to do it is by using a dictionary(although it maybe slower than lists). The below implementation is sort of a key-value pair data structure where every item is a "key" and its parent is a "value". hope it helps.

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;

class mytree
    {

```
        public static Dictionary<String, String> dict = new Dictionary<String, String>();

         public void dictionaryadd(String key, String value) 
    {
      dict.Add(key, value);
      }
      static List<int> GetKeysFromValue(Dictionary<string, string> dict, string value)
{
    // Use LINQ to do a reverse dictionary lookup.
    // Returns a 'List<T>' to account for the possibility
    // of duplicate values.
    return
        (from item in dict
         where item.Value.Equals(value)
         select item.Key).ToList();
}
       public String dictionaryout(String key)
    {
        string value;
        if(dict.TryGetValue(key,out value))
                return value; 
        else    return String.Empty;
     }

     }
```